# How can I get those information inside a process when I know PID of this process?

Tags: c, linux, process, kernel

[image]

I have problem, when I know PID of a process, so How can I get information blow by C :

Start stack > Start heap > End heap > Start code > End code > Start data >  End data
[image]

Comment: In Linux, you read `/proc/PID/maps`, for example.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I so sorry, this is my bad! thank you very much!